# Prove that $\int^3_0 \frac{1}{x^x}dx$ converges

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

How do you prove that $\int^3_0 \frac{1}{x^x}dx$ converges? I've learned the integral of $x^x$, but I don't think the question requires me to use it here as we have not been taught the integral of $x^x$ in class.

Comment: This is not really an improper integral as function as well as interval of integration is bounded. The problem here is that the formula for the function is undefined at $0$ and we are at liberty to define it in any manner. The resulting function thus has at most one discontinuity at thus the integral exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_{1}^{3}\frac{dx}{x^x}$ is obviously convergent, so the only issue is to show that $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x^x}$ is convergent.
On the other hand over $(0,1)$ we have $0\leq -x\log x\leq \sqrt{x}(1-x)$, hence

$$ 0\leq\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x^x}=\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x\log x}\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{1} e^{\sqrt{x}(1-x)}\,dx=2\int_{0}^{1}z e^{z(1-z^2)}\,dz $$
and the last integral is clearly bounded (by $\exp\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}$, for instance, since the maximum of $z-z^3$ over $[0,1]$ occurs at $z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$). It might be interesting to point out that this problem is related to [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream):

$$ \int_{0}^{1}e^{-x\log x}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}x^n \log^n x\,dx=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\cdot\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(n+1)^{n+1}} $$
hence $\color{red}{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x^x}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^n}}\leq 1+\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{3}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

One can show that on $[0,3]$, $\frac{1}{x^x}<2$, so $\frac{1}{x^x}$ is bounded, hence integrable over a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ so your integral converges.

Comment: How can you show that $\frac{1}{x^x}$ is always less than 2? It's not immediately obvious looking at the question as I thought the function will go to infinity as x approaches 0. Is there some vigorous way to do it without keying it into a calculator?

Comment: Let $y=x^x$, then $\log(y)=x\log(x)$ and $\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=\log(x)+1$ so $y'=x^x(1+log(x))$. We can show that $y$ is minimimilized in $x=1/e$, and $(1/e)^{(1/e)}>1/2$

Comment: I see, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that $\lim_{x\to0+}x\log x=0$. It follows that the function $f(x):=-x\log x$ $(x>0)$ can be continuously extended to the interval $[0,3]$ by putting $f(0):=0$. One then has
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to0+}\int_\epsilon^3 {1\over x^x}\>dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to0+}\int_\epsilon^3 e^{f(x)}\>dx=\int_0^3 e^{f(x)}\>dx\ .$$